# Parse.com deploying to old app after app cloning even though I no longer have access to the old app

Tags: parse-platform

I've cloned an app (the app was made initially by someone else, they've added me as a collaborator as I took the job, but for more security, I've cloned the app myself by using the new clone feature) and renamed the new project, but it's still deploying to the old app, even though I've removed myself from its collaborators. I haven't changed anything on my computer and (presumably) because they have the same name, `parse develop myappname` and `parse deploy` [seemed to] work.

Answer (score 0):

Just after I've posted the question, I've found the answer: it was the app key/master key pair. When I cloned the app, my app has been assigned new keys, but `~/config/global.json` still had the keys of the old app. I've changed the app key and the master key in that file with the new keys in my Parse settings, and it worked. It's now deploying to my new app. Wish it updated automatically, though.